# Azure Communication Services with Ionic

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, npm

I have a working project with Twilio + Ionic, but I'm wondering if you can help me with adding Azure Communication Services(video call) into my project. I tried to follow the example from the official website, but I think it's not just installing npm library and adding it as usual in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a working sample, you can use this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-hero

If you're still stuck, please respond here and I'll try to help you directly.

Answer (score -1):

Invalid CommunicationUser identifier specified